# call dml insert listofSObject from a controller that is referenced in apex page

Tags: apex, controller, dml

Is it possible to call dml operations like `insert list_SObject ;` inside a controller method that is refrenced in visualforce page not some trigger class? please give some references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this :

VF page :

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!controllerMethod}"/>
```

Controller :

```
public void controllerMethod() {
    // Do some stuff with your list

    insert list_SObject;
}
```